# SSL Error occurs on one computer but not the other?

Tags: python, ssl, asana

I can't figure out why all of a sudden the below code that uses Asana's API generates the below SSL error. Something must have changed on my laptop, since it runs perfectly on my other computer.

```
from asana import asana

class Login(object):
    def __init__(self):
        api = 'API'
        self.asana_api = asana.AsanaAPI(api, debug=False)
        self.user_id = 7359085011308L

class Test(Login):
    def Test(self):
        Id = 2467584555313L
        print self.asana_api.list_tasks(Id,self.user_id)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Chris/Dropbox/AsanaPullPush.py", line 75, in <module>
    if __name__ == "__main__": main()
  File "/Users/Chris/Dropbox/AsanaPullPush.py", line 72, in main
    print Test().Test()
  File "/Users/Chris/Dropbox/AsanaPullPush.py", line 15, in Test
    print self.asana_api.list_tasks(Id,self.user_id)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/asana/asana.py", line 174, in list_tasks
    return self._asana(target)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/asana/asana.py", line 74, in _asana
    r = requests.get(target, auth=(self.apikey, ""))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 55, in get
    return request('get', url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 383, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 486, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 389, in send
    raise SSLError(e)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:507: error:0D0890A1:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_verify:unknown message digest algorithm
```

Comment: Check versions of Python, versions of libraries, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We recently changed our SSL key in response to the Heartbleed bug you may have heard about. http://blog.asana.com/2014/04/heartbleed/

It looks like your laptop may not have the right SSL. See https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/829 for discussion of a similar issue.

You should be able to check SSL version on the two machines with `python -c "import ssl; print ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION"`. If indeed the laptop is behind, you'll need to update your python's SSL.

Comment: I had a gut feeling that had something to do with it. Thanks! Now, I can figure out how to solve this.