# Error trying to install Django with pip

Tags: python, ssl, pip, failed-installation

I get the following error when I do "pip install django" in OSX...

```
Downloading/unpacking django
  Error <urlopen error [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:0D0890A1:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_verify:unknown message digest algorithm> while getting https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.8.1.tar.gz#md5=0f0a677a2cd56b9ab7ccb1c562d70f53 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/)
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/garylewis/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 134, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Users/garylewis/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 236, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/Users/garylewis/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1092, in prepare_files
    self.unpack_url(url, location, self.is_download)
  File "/Users/garylewis/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1238, in unpack_url
    retval = unpack_http_url(link, location, self.download_cache, self.download_dir)
  File "/Users/garylewis/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 602, in unpack_http_url
    resp = _get_response_from_url(target_url, link)
  File "/Users/garylewis/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 638, in _get_response_from_url
    resp = urlopen(target_url)
  File "/Users/garylewis/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 176, in __call__
    response = self.get_opener(scheme=scheme).open(url)
  File "/Users/garylewis/anaconda/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Users/garylewis/anaconda/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/Users/garylewis/anaconda/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Users/garylewis/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 155, in https_open
    return self.do_open(self.specialized_conn_class, req)
  File "/Users/garylewis/anaconda/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1184, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:0D0890A1:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_verify:unknown message digest algorithm>

Storing complete log in /var/folders/tv/mxmczdzd00bb3z5zkm6q1l400000gn/T/tmpYaAhkf
```

How do I resolve this and install Django? I think it might be a problem with pip itself. I seem to recall being unable to install other Python stuff in the past with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error seems related the SSL Python's certificate as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23002438/ssl-error-occurs-on-one-computer-but-not-the-other). Certificates where updated because of the Heartbleed known bug. You need to update/reinstall your Python.

Comment: Thanks. I installed the latest version of Python but I don't know how to tell pip to use it instead of Python 2.7. I also tried following the steps in http://stackoverflow.com/a/3819829/805141 to uninstall Python 2.7 but it didn't seem to work

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall pip and install it again with your new version of Python?

Comment: Nope. Trying to figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I search the problem and find this question. But I find there is no solution for this problem. I share my solution as follows:

1. As shown in the question, anaconda is used.  Please try to use the **conda install**. If return HTTP 403, you have the same problem as mine. I think the reason lies in the old anaconda version.
2. I **solve this problem** by uninstall the anaconda and reinstall it. My system is macOS.